# How to make sure that two addresses have the least significant 4 bits the same?

Tags: c, bit, memory-address

So I have two pointers:

```
unsigned char * a;
unsigned char * b;
```

Let's assume that I used malloc and they are allocated of a certain size.
I want to make the least significant 4 bits of the address of the pointers to be the same... but I really don't know how.

First of all I want to take the least significant 4 bits from `a`. I tried something like

```
int least = (&a) & 0x0f;
```

but I get an error that & is an invalid operand. I was thinking to allocate more for `b` and search for an address that has the least significant 4 bits the same as `a` but I really have no idea how I can do that.

Comment: Why would you need/do this? Seems like a nasty UB hack.

Comment: you used & when you wanted to use &&

Comment: I am working with cell and I want to use mfc_put to send 4 bytes at the time and I have to have the least significant 4 bits of the address of the source and destination the same

Comment: You need to cast the pointers to integer types before using the bitwise operations. It's still UB, but it will probably do what you expect.

Comment: @PeteFordham The reason of being of `uintptr_t` is that casting a pointer to it should be implementation-defined, not UB.

Comment: @IonelMerca - Please explain the motivation for doing this? I am intrigued.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char *a;
    unsigned char *b;

    a = malloc(8);
    b = malloc(8);

    if (((uintptr_t)a & 0x0F) == ((uintptr_t)b & 0x0F)) {
        printf("Yeah, the least 4 bits are the same.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Nope, the least 4 bits are not the same.\n");
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use uintptr_t rather than ptrdiff_t.

Comment: @PeteFordham: I think it doesn't matter in this case, but `uintptr_t` is probably ideologically more correct. From what I can tell in practice, `unsigned long` usually suits Linux kernel developers well.

Comment: SO if I want to find the address that has the least significant 4 bits the same like A how do I do that ?

Comment: and of all but the last 4 bits as above, then add any multiple of 16 you want to that value.  They will have the same low 4-bits.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here though...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char *a, *b;

    a = malloc(32);
    b = a + 16;

    printf("%p %p\n", a, b); // You should see that their least significative
                             // 4-bits are equal
}
```

Since `a` and `b` are 16 byte apart and part of a contiguous memory block, their addresses should have the property you want.

Comment: You don't actually describe how to check if the low 4-bits are the same.

Comment: Yeah, this snippet guarantees that both a and b have the same low 4-bits, so OP wouldn't have to check them. I tried to answer the question in the title. I agree that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
int least;

least = (int)(&a) ^ (int)(&b); //this is a bitwise XOR, returning 0s when the bits are the same

if (least % 16) = 0 then
{
     //first four bits are zeroes, meaning they all match
}
```

Comment: Hm, it seems like you are taking addresses of pointers, not values of pointers.

Comment: I thought that was what he was asking for in the question: "I want to make the least significant 4 bits of the address of the pointers to be the same..."

Comment: -1 `&a` and `&b` are pointers and `^` is not defined for pointers. C doesn't have `mod` either.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze whoops I meant to use the `%` operator, not `mod`.  Fixed.

Comment: c doesn't have static_cast either :P

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Yikes, been coding in too many different languages lately.  Also helps to check the tags lol.

Comment: NP - now people are going to complain that your are type-casting a pointer to an int, which is probably undefined behavior.  Personally, I'm fine with it though.  The xor is interesting.  My first soultion would be & 0xf as the above answer, but this does work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this problem is to use an allocation function that will only return allocations that are aligned on 16 byte boundaries (therefore the least significant 4 bits will be always be zero).

Some platforms have such alignment-guaranteed allocation functions such as `_aligned_malloc()` in MSVC or `posix_memalign()` on Unix variants.  If you don't have such an allocator available, returning an aligned block of memory using plain vanilla `malloc()` is a common interview question - an internet search will net you many possible solutions.